# R: How to use rmarkdown to correct render ioslides table with 3 columns?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

```
## Arithmetic in R

Operation  | Usage | Example 
------------- | ------------- | -------------
Addition  | a + b | 
Subtraction  | a - b | 
Mulitplication  | a * b | 
Divison  | a / b | 
Exponetiation | a ^ b or a ** b | 
Modulo | a %% b | 5 %% 3 gives 2
Matrix Mult | a %*% b | hello
```

I have the above code in rmarkdown in ioslides to create a table. However the last row of the table only renders two columns with the second column containing

> a%*%b | hello

instead of putting hello onto the third column? Is this a bug?

Comment: have you tried adding a line of dashes at the end of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting rid of the pipes made it work for me:

```
Operation         Usage             Example 
---------------   ---------------   -------------
Addition          a + b              
Subtraction       a - b              
Mulitplication    a * b              
Divison           a / b              
Exponetiation     a ^ b or a ** b    
Modulo            a %% b            5 %% 3 gives 2
Matrix Mult       a %*% b           hello
```

[image]